# How to return first and last values in a column using openpyxl and change the title of the excel file to them?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to change the title of five files to show the first and last values in a column in that file separated by a "_"

For example, in a column if I have values 0001,0002,0003,0004, I want to find the first and last value and change the title of the file to 0001_0004

```
files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in files:
if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print(file)
    try: 
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file))
        print('reading workbook'+file)
        ws=wb['Sheet1'] 
        for row in range(7, ws.max_row+1):
            cell = ws.cell(row = row, column = 7)
            #code to change name
            wb.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file))
        print('file title changed') 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: and what issue are you encountering with your code?

Comment: I am unable to find anything that will allow me to find the value of the cell at the first and last row in the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
all_xls = []
for f in files:
   if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
       all_xls.append(f.replace('.xls', '')

all_xls.sort()
first_file = all_xls[0]
last_file = all_xls[-1]
#Do your renaming using os.rename('src', 'dest')
```

This is a just a quick solution I could think of and it is not the optimal solution, you can tweak it up to get the desired results faster.

hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me reach my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56776105/11672154)

Answer (score 0):

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print(filename)
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),filename), data_only = True)
        ws = wb['Sheet1']
        final = ws.max_row
        original_file = str(filename)
        cell = ws['G7'].value
        filenamep1 = cell
        cell = ws.cell(row = final, column = 7).value
        filenamep2 = cell
        os.rename(original_file, path + '\\' + filenamep1 + '_' + filenamep2 + '_' + 
        original_file)
print("All files renamed")
```

This is what I ended up using to rename the file